# How to show error from API below Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table, material-table, angular-material-table

I'm facing the following problem.

I want to present error from API which applies to the entire table. In my case I want to show error that table has no rows. I'm able to present error using mat-error, however when I fill it, error is not hiding. I wish to have error which show and hide like in stock control (for example: mat-input).

Below my html code.

```
<mat-form-field color="accent" class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <input matInput name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel" placeholder="Name">
  <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">{{name.errors.api}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="converters" [ngModel]="converterItems.data" #converters="ngModel">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="converterItems" name="converters">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Key </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.key}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="typeName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Type name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.typeName}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsConverters"></tr>
  <tr [@rowsAnimation]="" mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsConverters;" (click)="select(row)"
      [ngClass]="{ 'selected': row === selectedRow }"></tr>
</table>
<mat-error *ngIf="converters.invalid" class="errorTextSize">{{converters.errors.api}}</mat-error>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
this.appService.getService().subcribe(result => {
    // Do something when the service returns successfully
},
error => {
    // Do something when the service returns with an error like below:
    this.converters.invalid=true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. However it won't work. What if I will fill table without sending? Converter will still be in invalid status. I could fix it by checking when I add something to table. However is very dirty solution.